# How do I loop xml file and get the values in c# code

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm trying to`loop` the below code in c# and getting `count = 0`

I was doing as below code

```
 foreach (XmlNode intraday_series in source_file.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//IntradayStructuring "))
      {
      }
```

But still `intraday_series is 0`

[image: xml]

Comment: You are missing the namespace. So that's reason why result == 0.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370989/which-xpath-expression-will-allow-me-to-select-these-nodes

Comment: you have a trailing space in the XPath Query. Did you check it

Comment: The file has XMLSchema namespace and the file was saved as xml rather than xsd then...? While loading the file I can add xml namespace and do you think that should work?

Comment: Also, are you able to get the list of elements by applying this Xpath in the quick watch or immediate window.

Comment: Your IntradayStructuring elements are in the namespace `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet1`. You need to use an XmlNamespaceManager to assign a prefix to that namespace and then refer to the elements with that prefix. Please see the link I already posted above.

Comment: @saravanan I was getting all the data in innerxml but i don't need in that way. I need to loop each node and get the values.But the selectNodes doesn't retrieve anything and count is 0

Comment: @JLRishe yeah I was looking into that mate

Comment: @JLRishe what should I can add this line in my case..? m.AddNamespace("myns", "url1");

Comment: @user1990395: did you remove the space in the xpath query.

Comment: @JLRishe Thanks for the link got it in the loop.. cheers mate