# Getting all entry Elements within a Namespace from XML using XPath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xmldocument

I'm trying to get all the entry elements so I can display them, haven't done Xpath for a while but I thought it would be fairly simple heres what I have so far - rssNodes count is 0, what am I missing?

```
XmlDocument rssXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
rssXmlDoc.Load("http://www.businessopportunities.ukti.gov.uk/alertfeed/1425362.rss");

var rssNodes = rssXmlDoc.SelectNodes("feed/entry");
```

The XML file has the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <!-- some other child elements -->
  <entry>
    <!-- child elements -->
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <!-- child elements -->
  </entry>
  <!-- more entry elements -->
  <!-- some other child elements -->
</feed>
```

Comment: Can you show your XML?

Comment: Follow the link > http://www.businessopportunities.ukti.gov.uk/alertfeed/1425362.rss

Comment: possible duplicate of [which xpath expression will allow me to select these nodes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370989/which-xpath-expression-will-allow-me-to-select-these-nodes)

Comment: I updated your question title to narrow down the problem. Also, I took the liberty of including the essential parts of the XML file.

Comment: @helb thank you, if you can you could look at the last part for me too :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29413435/using-xpath-to-get-element-from-xmlnode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to properly use namespaces:

```
var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(rssXmlDoc.NameTable);
nsm.AddNamespace("atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");

var entries = rssXmlDoc.SelectNodes("/atom:feed/atom:entry", nsm);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to respect XML namespaces with XPath.

**NOTE**: If the namespace of the `entry` element is known, see JLRishe's answer which is more elegant in that case.

If you don't know the XML namespace beforehand you can also ignore it using the XPath built-in `local-name()` function:

```
SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='entry']")
```

This will get all `entry` elements in the entire XML document, no matter which namespace the element belongs to.