# Using Xpath to get Element from XmlNode

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xmldocument

I'm trying to get the title and link of each entry in this xml feed

https://www.businessopportunities.ukti.gov.uk/alertfeed/businessopportunities.rss

Setting a breakpoint I can see that I am getting all the entries but I am getting an error when I try and get the title or link from the entry

```
XmlDocument rssXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
rssXmlDoc.Load("https://www.businessopportunities.ukti.gov.uk/alertfeed/businessopportunities.rss");
var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(rssXmlDoc.NameTable);
nsm.AddNamespace("atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");

XmlNodeList entries = rssXmlDoc.SelectNodes("/atom:feed/atom:entry", nsm);


foreach (XmlNode entry in entries)
{
    var title = entry.SelectSingleNode("/atom:entry/atom:title", nsm).InnerText;
    var link = entry.SelectSingleNode("/atom:entry/atom:link", nsm).InnerText;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In an XPath expression, a leading `/` indicates that the expression should be evaluated starting from the *root* node of the document. This kind of expression is called an *absolute* path expression. Your first expression:

```
/atom:feed/atom:entry
```

really *should* be evaluated starting from the root, but all subsequent expressions should not. An expression like

```
/atom:entry/atom:title
```

means

> Start at the root node of the document, then look for the outermost element `atom:entry`, then select its child elements called `atom:title`.

But obviously, `atom:entry` is not the outermost element of the document.

Simply change

```
var title = entry.SelectSingleNode("/atom:entry/atom:title", nsm).InnerText;
var link = entry.SelectSingleNode("/atom:entry/atom:link", nsm).InnerText;
```

to

```
var title = entry.SelectSingleNode("atom:title", nsm).InnerText;
var link = entry.SelectSingleNode("atom:link", nsm).InnerText;
```