# Issue with get xpath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am trying to read some data from xml. below is my xml structure.

```
 <Configuration> 
<node1></node1> 
<unity
 xmlns=xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
 <namesapce name="somename"/> . . . 
</unity> 
</Configuration>
```

I have tried to read the node "unity" using below xpath

```
 var nodelist=doc.SelectNodes("/configuration/unity[@xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity']");
```

But it returns null. Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Well your XML is broken, you have `xmlns=xmlns="..."` when there should be just one `xmlns="..."`.  Assuming that's a typo in the question, the `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity"` is an [XML namespace declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace#Namespace_declaration) so you need to follow the instructions in [How do I select nodes that use a default namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14370989) and [Using Xpath With Default Namespace in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/585812).

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (Ignoring namespace)

```
    string xmlString = "<Configuration><node1></node1><unity xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity\"><namesapce name=\"somename\"/></unity></Configuration>";
    XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
    xd.LoadXml(xmlString);
    var nodes = xd.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='unity']");

    Console.WriteLine(nodes.Count);
```